# ant script cant support nested If statement?

Tags: ant, build, ivy

Hi i am trying to build an ant script that copies a certain lib file based on a if condition. however it doesnt seem to work as i get this error:

build.xml:20: fileset doesn't support the nested "if" element.

this is the part where it fails:

```
<target name="resolve">
        <delete dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*" />
        </delete>

        <copy todir="${lib.dir}">
            <fileset dir="ext-libs" >
                <if name="${release}" value="true">
                    <include name="hello-client-[^DEBUG]*.jar" />
                </if>
                <else>
                    <include name="hello-client-*DEBUG.*.jar" />
                </else>

            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**@JoseK** is right. ANT filesets do not support nested "if" statements. In fact the "if" statement is not part of core ANT the recommended approach is to use conditional targets (See example)

**@slipset** is on the right track. [Ivy configurations](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/conf.html) can be used to selectively choose your dependencies.

## Example

This example is designed to be invoked in one of two ways

```
$ ant clean build
$ tree
.
|-- build.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- lib
    |-- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
    `-- slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
```

Or

```
$ ant -Drelease=1 clean build
$ tree
.
|-- build.xml
|-- ivy.xml
`-- lib
    |-- logback-classic-1.0.3.jar
    |-- logback-core-1.0.3.jar
    `-- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

    <target name="retrieve-alt" depends="resolve" unless="release">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="altruntime"/>
    </target>

    <target name="retrieve-release" depends="resolve" if="release">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="runtime"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="retrieve-alt,retrieve-release"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="lib"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The **if** and **unless** clauses on the targets perform a conditional test on the existence of the "release" property.
- The ivy **retrieve** task uses a configuration to decide which jars should be used to populate the "lib" directory.
- The **retrieve** pattern includes a "classifier" pattern, just in case you ivy mapping pulls down additional Maven artifacts like the source or javadoc jars.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="altruntime"   description="Alternative 'runtime' configuration" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="altruntime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency org="ch.qos.logback" name="logback-classic" rev="1.0.3" conf="runtime->default"/>

        <!-- altruntime dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.6.4" conf="altruntime->default"/>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.10" conf="test->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Note:

- I would highly recommend always specifying a configuration mapping for each dependency. This will then map directly to how you intend to use the jars, for example populate a classpath.

## Appendix

### How to use ivy configurations

Ivy configurations can be used to emulate Maven scopes, but in fact an ivy configuration can represent any logical grouping of dependencies.

Here are the 3 standard classpaths required in any Java build:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
    <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
</configurations>
```

Note the "extends" syntax that enables you to create larger sets. For example, the **runtime** set of jars also includes anything needed to **compile** the code your code.

Ivy configurations are difficult to understand until you realise that they can be used to selectively populate an ANT path:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>

<javac ..... classpathref="compile.path"/>
```

Or used to selectively populate a directory

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="build/WEB-INF/lib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>
```

### Configuration mappings

Mappings are used to decide how groups of jars in your project relate to groups of jars in other projects.

This normally happens as follows:

```
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4" conf="compile->default"/>
```

Here our **compile** configuration is populate by the remote **default** configuration (normally the other modules compile dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the [apache docs are clear](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) that you cannot nest an `<if>` within a `<fileset>`

You might have seen an example of the [ant-contrib fileset task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/fileset.html) which **does** have the `if` as a conditional argument

You can [download](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this a bit differently myself.
I've got

```
<target name="internal-resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern = "${basedir}/lib/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" conf = "${configuration}" />
</target>
```

Which puts the jars in a directory called `lib/${configuration}` where configuration is passed as a parameter in

```
 <target name = "resolve-compile">
    <antcall target = "internal-resolve">
        <param name = "configuration" value = "compile"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

So whenever resolve-compile is called, the jars are put in `lib/compile`.
This gives me:

```
<path id = "compile.class.path">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/compile" includes="*.jar"/>
</path>
```

and finally

```
    <target name="compile" 
          depends="init, resolve-compile"
          description="Compile all Java-classes">
    <javac deprecation="false"
           encoding="utf8"
           debug="true"
           srcdir="${java.src.dir}"
           destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
           classpathref="compile.class.path"/>
  </target>
```

Given this, you could easily created your own `resolve-build` which would drop your jars in `lib/build`

Granted, you'd then need to add a `build` configuration to your ivy.xml as

```
  <configurations>
      <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="Whatever"/>
      <conf name="build" visibility="public" description="Whatever"/>
  </configuration>
```